How to Handle Base64-Encoded Signed Transactions in Rust
does anyone know the correct way to handle a string payload that is a signed transaction in Uint8Array format encoded in base64?
const signedTransactionDecoded = base58.decode(transaction);
const signedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(
    signedTransactionDecoded
);

I want to achieve something similar to this, but in Rust, and I haven’t been able to find a solution yet.
That's what I've tried so far:
    let signed_transaction_decoded = bincode::deserialize(&payload.transaction.as_bytes())
        .map_err(|e| {
            (
                StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                format!("Invalid transaction ID: {}", e),
            )
        })?;

    let signed_transaction = VersionedTransaction::verify_with_results(&signed_transaction_decoded)
        .map_err(|e| {
            (
                StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                format!("Invalid signed transaction: {}", e),
            )
        })?;


To handle a Base64-encoded signed transaction in Rust, you can follow these steps:
Decode the Base64 string to get the original binary data (similar to how Base58 decode would work).
Deserialize the binary data to the desired struct using an appropriate deserialization method.
Here's a simplified example:
Add necessary dependencies in your Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]  
base64 = "0.13" # For decoding base64 encoded strings  
bincode = "1.3" # For deserialization of binary data  

Your Rust code would look something like this:
use base64::decode;  
use bincode;  
use your_crate::VersionedTransaction; // Ensure this is your actual crate/module  

fn handle_signed_transaction(base64_str: &str) -> Result<VersionedTransaction, String> {  
    // Step 1: Decode the Base64 string  
    let decoded_bytes = decode(base64_str).map_err(|e| {  
        format!("Failed to decode base64: {}", e)  
    })?;  

    // Step 2: Deserialize the binary data to a VersionedTransaction  
    let signed_transaction: VersionedTransaction = bincode::deserialize(&decoded_bytes).map_err(|e| {  
        format!("Failed to deserialize transaction: {}", e)  
    })?;  

    // If successful, return the deserialized VersionedTransaction  
    Ok(signed_transaction)  
}  

fn main() {  
    let base64_str = "your_base64_encoded_transaction_string_here";  
    match handle_signed_transaction(base64_str) {  
        Ok(transaction) => {  
            println!("Successfully deserialized transaction: {:?}", transaction);  
        },  
        Err(e) => {  
            println!("Error: {}", e);  
        }  
    }  
}  

Explanation:

decode: This function decodes the Base64-encoded string into the original binary format (Vec).
bincode::deserialize: Deserializes the binary data into a VersionedTransaction struct. Adjust VersionedTransaction based on how you import or define it in your project.
Error Handling: Proper error handling with descriptive messages helps in debugging.

With this approach, you can decode and deserialize the Base64-encoded signed transaction in Rust similar to your JavaScript example. Make sure to replace your_crate::VersionedTransaction with the actual path to the VersionedTransaction struct in your project.

It seemed to work so far. Thank you so much @mumut3k!

You are welcome!
